# How to set variable value at x[3]=6 (not initial condition) in Python Gekko?

Tags: python, simulation, gekko

I can set an initial condition y(0)=5 in Gekko with `y = m.Var(5)` but how do I set a value that is not the initial condition such as y(3)=6 where the value at time=3 is 6 as shown by the red dot?

[image: Specify internal point]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,10,11)
x = m.Var(np.ones(11)*6)
m.Equation(5*x.dt() == -x)
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve()
plt.plot(m.time, x.value)
plt.plot([3],[6],'ro',MarkerSize=5)
plt.show()
```

I have a simulation problem where I need the solution to arrive at intermediate values along the time horizon `m.time = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. When I initialize with `x=m.Var(np.ones(11)*6)` the values are later changed by the solver. Can I fix one of the values not at the initial condition? This is similar to a boundary value problem where the beginning or end points is fixed but in this case a specified value is internal to the time horizon.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to make the initial condition calculated with `fixed_initial=False` option when you specify `x=m.Var()`. The model building function `m.fix()` can fix any point in the horizon such as with `m.fix(x,pos=3,val=6)` but this also fixes the derivative at that point.

An alternative method is to specify an objective to minimize the deviation from the value of `6` at time=3.

```py
pi = np.zeros(11); pi[3]=1
p = m.Param(pi)
m.Minimize(p*(x-6)**2)
```

This creates the objective everywhere but `p` is only non-zero at time=3.

[image: Free initial condition]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,10,11)
x = m.Var(np.zeros(11)*6,fixed_initial=False)
m.Equation(5*x.dt() == -x)
pi = np.zeros(11); pi[3]=1
p = m.Param(pi)
m.Minimize(p*(x-6)**2)
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()
plt.plot(m.time, x.value)
plt.plot([3],[6],'ro',MarkerSize=5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Bryson benchmark problem (see #2)](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MidtermExam2016) shows four ways to fix values that are not initial conditions.

```py
if option == 1:
    # most likely to cause DOF issues because of many 
    #  zero (0==0) equations
    m.Equation(final*x1 == 0)
    m.Equation(final*x2 == 0) 
elif option == 2:
    # inequality constraint approach is better but there
    #   are still many inactive equations
    m.Equation((final*x1)**2 <= 0)
    m.Equation((final*x2)**2 <= 0)
elif option == 3: #requires GEKKO version >= 0.0.3a2
    # fix the value just at the endpoint (best option)
    m.fix(x1,pos=nt-1,val=0)
    m.fix(x2,pos=nt-1,val=0)
else:
    #penalty method ("soft constraint") that may influence
    # optimal solution because there is just one
    # combined objective and it may interfere with
    # minimizing myObj
    m.Obj(1000*(final*x1)**2)
    m.Obj(1000*(final*x2)**2)

m.Obj(myObj*final)
```

This code could be adapted to have a point in the middle.